# Unused property OnPrepare

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm getting an issue with the `OnPrepare` in the protractor configuration file. Somehow the functions became `Unused property` and now I'm not able to use the configurations for browser and reports.

Does somebody have a similar issue to mine?

Comment: In addition, I did some research and when I've opened the project with VS Code there have no problems... so something having with Webstorm and protractor configuration file.

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem is

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. everything is fine!

Comment: @NedyalkoGeorgiev glad you got the issue sorted, would you mind deleting the question considering it was a user error. Otherwise people will likely vote to close your question

Comment: I've just encountered this problem and can confirm that this appears to be a webstorm-related issue: Webstorm marks the onPrepare in my config-file as "Unused property (...)", however, the statements that are declared in onPrepare get executed prior to the test.